# Hazelcast High Density Memory Store

Tags: java, hazelcast

As per Hazelcast documentation, there are 2 different implementations of HD Memory :-
    1. an on-heap SLAB Allocator that uses heap memory.
    2. a native memory implementation that allocates the memory using “sun.misc.Unsafe” outside of JVM heap.

" Only the native memory-based implementation is exposed to the end users.(here i'm assuming exposed to end users means public APIs)"

Now, my doubt is What is the use of an on-heap SLAB Allocator then since no public APIs are there for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Native memory or simple heap usage based cache, there are no APIs to access the memory. Hazelcast exposes APIs to access the data stored in data structures.

You can configure compatible data structures to use Native memory instead of on-heap memory. Usage from application does not change - no APIs need to change hands.

For example, data in IMap is by default stored on the heap but when you change the configuration for Native, the data gets stored in Native memory; and your applications do not even see this change as this change is on servers, unless you are using Near Cache.

Comment: @Wildnez...i understood what you're trying to say...but what is the use of on-heap Slab Allocator implementation of HD-Memory?